# Need to implement do, while loop to class

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to create a simple loop whereby there are 20 tables in the restaurant. A customer will be able to choose tables from 1 to 20. So I created an if else statement for it. But if a customer enters a number which is out of the boundary, it will print an error message. The thing is, I want it to re-ask the same question again if user enters wrongly, so I tried a do while loop. Problem is, the output is error-strewn. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class MainRestaurant {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose your table from 1-20.");

    int table;
    int x = 1;

    table = sc.nextInt();

    do{
      if(table >0 && table <21){
        System.out.println("Table chosen: " + table);
        x=2;
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Wrong choice");
      }
    }while(x==1);
  }
```

Comment: How do you want `x` to be updated?

Comment: Coding guideline: Don't use `int` for a `boolean` in languages that have a boolean type. Instead of `int x = 1;`, try `boolean tableChosen = false;`. Then it's `tableChosen = true` for `x=2` and `while (!tableChosen)` for `while(x==1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified version of ur code

public class MainRestaurant {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please choose your table from 1-20.");

int table;
int x = 1;

do{
  table = sc.nextInt(); // every time the user will input the number
  if(table >0 && table <21){
    System.out.println("Table chosen: " + table);
    x=2;
  }
  else{
    System.out.println("Wrong choice");
  }
}while(x==1);
```

}

Comment: This is probably homework, in my opinion. I would avoid giving out working code. It discourages learning.

Comment: Ya u r ryt jpmc26..but somebody have to help him out!

Answer (score 2):

You should move the sc.nextInt() function in to the do-while loop.

```
do{
    table = sc.nextInt();
    if(table >0 && table <21){
        System.out.println("Table chosen: " + table);
        x=2;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Wrong choice");
    }

} while(x==1);
```

Answer (score 0):

move this `table = sc.nextInt();` line inside your `do while loop`

Answer (score 0):

`table = sc.nextInt();` should be in the `do-while` loop (i.e. after `do{`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose your table from 1-20.");

    int table;
    int x = 1;

    do{
    table = sc.nextInt(); //put the sc.nextInt() inside de loop
    if(table >0 && table <21){
        System.out.println("Table chosen: " + table);
        x=2;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Wrong choice");
    }
    }while(x==1);
sc.close(); //don't forget to close the scanner
```